# what is the difference between the java.lang.Math class and the java.Math class

Tags: java, numbers, bigdecimal, java.lang.class

I am trying to figure out which 'Library'  the BigDecimal Class resides in.  When I read the referencing information it says this:

```
java.lang.Object
     java.lang.Number
          java.math.BigDecimal
```

which I don't totally understand.  I am familiar with the java.lang.Math class.  I assume this is entirely different - so here are my sub-questions:

First - am I correct in saying that the java Math class resides in the java.lang library

second -  Does java.math.BigDecimal extend java.lang.Number, and if not, how are they related?

Third - is there a relationship to java.lang.math and java.math?

Comment: not library -- **package**.

Comment: One is a class, the other is an (incorrectly capitalised) package.

Comment: The above is an inheritance diagram.  BigDecimal inherits from Number which inherits from Object.  java.lang.Math is not in the same hierarchy but inherits directly from Object (the ultimate "parent" of all classes).  What package a class resides in has little to do with it's inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You speak of packages, not libraries.

A package is a place where many class files go. A class has two names. One simple name, `Math`, and one qualified name with the package as a suffix, `java.lang.Math`. This makes it possible for Java developers to use in their program many classes of the same simple name, say "Stream" for example. Many different "streams" may share the same simple name but be logically grouped into different *namespaces*, or *packages* if you will. A package must not be mapped to folders, but for most Java projects, that's how they are mapped and hence you may call this practice a "de facto standard".

A library is basically a file that contains compiled class files so that you can use these Java types in your program without having to reinvent the wheel.

The Java Development Kit (JDK) include a lot of libraries for you, most notably `rt.jar`. On my Windows x64 machine, it is located here:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib

If you open `rt.jar` using any program that knows how to open ZIP files, you'll find the compiled class file `Math.class` in subfolder `./java/lang/`.

The answer to both your two first questions is **yes**. Let code be the judge:

```
// package java.lang, Java Platform API Specification, version 1.8
System.out.println(Math.class.getPackage());

// class java.lang.Number
System.out.println(BigDecimal.class.getSuperclass());
```

Answer (score 2):

**First:** Yes it resides there... **just look at the documentation**.

**Second:** Yes it extends the abstract class Number.java. **Again look at the documentation.**

**Third:** `java.lang.Math`

> contains methods for performing basic numeric operations such as the
>   elementary exponential, logarithm, square root, and trigonometric
>   functions.

in the context of BigDecimal "math" is just a package name.
`java.lang.Math` is a java class!

Think about a **package** as it was a folder in your computer. It's a 'namespace' a way to organise classes and interfaces together.
The package **[java.math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/package-use.html#java.math)** contains math related classes like BigDecimal.java and BigInteger.java

While the class java.lang.Math is an actual [Java class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html) which resides in the packae 'java.lang'

So **BigDecimal.java** and **Math.java** are both Java classes that resides **in two different 'packages'** (think of folders) even if they're both "Math" related .

Comment: Mentioning Java coding conventions (especially, naming of package and classes) would be good improvement on this answer.

Comment: I find the documentation confusing, which is why, even after looking at the documentation, I had to ask the question...maybe you could help me further, by explaining the documentation a bit...when the documentation places a library under another one, it just means that one extends the other, it doesn't mean that one is located in the other right?

Comment: @RoryG It doesn't place libraries (call them packages) under others, it places classes under other classes.